# What Java function offsetByCodePoints really takes as an argument?

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to understand some String class functions in Java. So, here's is a simple code:

```
/* different experiments with String class */

public class TestStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String greeting = "Hello\uD835\uDD6b";

        System.out.println("Number of code units in greeting is " + greeting.length());
        System.out.println("Number of code points " + greeting.codePointCount(0,greeting.length()));

        int index = greeting.offsetByCodePoints(0,6);
        System.out.println("index = " + index);
        int cp = greeting.codePointAt(index);
        System.out.println("Code point at index is " + (char) cp);
    }
}
```

\uD835\uDD6b is an ℤ symbol, so it's ok surrogate pair.

So, the string has 6(six) code points and 7(seven) code units (2-byte chars). As it's in documentation:

> `offsetByCodePoints`
>
> ```
> public int offsetByCodePoints(int index,
>                               int codePointOffset)
> ```
>
> Returns the index within this String that is offset from the given index by codePointOffset code points. 
>   Unpaired surrogates within the text range given by index and codePointOffset count as one code point each.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `index` - the index to be offset
>
> `codePointOffset` - the offset in code points

So we do give an argument in *code points*. But, with given arguments (0,6) it still works fine, without exceptions. But fails for codePointAt(), because it returns 7 which is out of bounds. So, maybe the function gets its args in code units? Or I've missed something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`codePointAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) takes a `char` index.

> The index refers to char values (Unicode code units) and ranges from `0` to `length() - 1`.

There are six code-points in that string.  The `offsetByCodePoints` call returns the index after 6 code-points which is char-index 7.  You then try to get the `codePointAt(7)` which is at the end of the string.

To see why, consider what

```
"".offsetByCodePoints(0, 0) == 0
```

because to count past all 0 code-points, you have to count past all 0 `char`s.

Extrapolating that to your string, to count past all `6` code-points, you have to count past all 7 `char`s.

Maybe seeing `codePointAt` in use will make this clear.  This is the idiomatic way to iterate over all code-points in a string (or `CharSequence`):

```
for (var charIndex = 0, nChars = s.length(), codepoint;
     charIndex < nChars;
     charIndex += Character.charCount(codepoint)) {
  codepoint = s.codePointAt(charIndex);
  // Do something with codepoint.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But the *strange* thing about discussed code is that int index = greeting.offsetByCodePoints(0,6); actually returns not 6, but 7! That looks quite weird, assuming that the index of the greatest code unit is 6 and 5 for code point (counting from 0).

Comment: @UgnichenkoDmitriy, Ah.  On rereading the javadoc, yes, `offsetByCodePoints` returns a char index so that makes sense.  Edited my post.

Comment: Oh, you may call me stupid, but still can't get -- where this 7 (seven) comes from?! The greatest index is 6, that if the index of the first char (or code unit) is 0. But where does seven come from? Yep, we have seven chars, but as I said it's a bit different with indexes.

Comment: `"".offsetByCodePoints(0, 0)` has to equal zero because there's no other reasonable value to return.  So in that case, counting all the code-points in the empty string returns the least index that is out of bounds.  Extrapolating that to your string, counting from 0 to the number of codepoints returns the least char-index that is out of bounds -- 7 in this case.

Comment: I've also commented the `String#offsetByCodePoints` method since it was quite confusing for me :)...

Answer (score 1):

Helpful answer, Mike... For easily understanding `String#offsetByCodePoints`, I commented its usage and modified a bit of the question example:

I personally find the Java documentation ambiguous here.

```
public class TestStrings
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String greeting = "Hello\uD835\uDD6b";

        // Gets the `char` index a.k.a. offset of the code point
        // at the code point index `0` starting from the `char` index `6`¹.
        // ---
        // Since `6` refers to an "unpaired" low surrogate (\uDD6b), the
        // returned value is 6 + 1 = 7.
        //
        int charIndex = greeting.offsetByCodePoints(0,6);

        System.out.println("charIndex = " + charIndex);

        int cp = greeting.codePointAt(charIndex);
        System.out.println("Code point at index is " + (char) cp);
    }
}
```